# Use slideToggle for repetitive classes

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide

I'm working with jQuery's `slideToggle` for open and close boxes.

The code works with classes in order to call the slide. That works fine, however, I'd like to use this slide for more than one box. When using two or more, when clicking on one of them, it opens all the boxes instead one clicked itself.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-extra-box").click(function(){
    $(".haja").slideToggle(250);
  });
});
```

And here the HTML:

```
<div class="nav-extra-box"></div>
<div class="haja">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>

<div class="nav-extra-box"></div>
<div class="haja">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>

<div class="nav-extra-box"></div>
<div class="haja">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a class selector, which returns a pseudo-array of objects, calling `.slideToggle()` on that array will call that function on *each* of those items.

Instead, you want to find *only the next* div of the desired class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-extra-box").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".haja").slideToggle(250);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to identify the element clicked and the open/close the div next to it using `next()` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-extra-box").click(function(){
    $(this).next('.haja').slideToggle(250);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-extra-box">a</div>
<div class="haja">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>

<div class="nav-extra-box">b</div>
<div class="haja">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>

<div class="nav-extra-box">c</div>
<div class="haja">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```